# reftex does not recognize references even though default bibliography file is defined

Tags: latex, auctex, reftex-mode

`reftex-citep` does not suggest any possible completions, even though the variable `reftex-default-bibliography` is set to the correct bibtex file.

What else do I need to do to get reftex to detect the bibtex entries?

Note: the same happens with the AuCTeX cite macro.

Comment: It seems that you might be a bit confused. `reftex-default-bibiography` isn't a variable but a function. I can't help you much, but please refer to `reftex`'s manual by evaluating the following s-exp: `(info "(reftex) Citations")`.

Comment: @aadcg: there is *both* a variable *and* a function named `reftex-default-bibliography`. The function returns the expanded value the variable. Presumably setting the variable is a necessary (but maybe not sufficient) condition for `reftex` to work.

Answer (score 2):

The doc for the `reftex-default-bibliography` variable says:

> List of BibTeX database files which should be used if none are specified.
> When ‘reftex-citation’ is called from a document which has neither a
> ‘\bibliography{..}’ statement nor a ‘thebibliography’ environment,
> RefTeX will scan these files instead.  Intended for using ‘reftex-citation’
> in non-LaTeX files.  The files will be searched along the BIBINPUTS or TEXBIB
> path.

Note that it is supposed to be a *list* of BibTeX database files. If you only have one, try saying

```
(setq reftex-default-bibliography '("/path/to/my/bibtex/file"))
```

EDIT: I downloaded Nelson Beebe's `ACM Computing Surveys` file from http://www.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/bib/compsurv.bib and  added it to `reftex-default-bibliography` with:

```el
(setq reftex-default-bibliography '("~/lib/bibtex/compsurv.bib"))
```

I put this in a file `minimal.el`.

In a brand new session of emacs (started with `emacs -q -l minimal.el foo.tex`), I enabled `reftex` with `M-x reftex-mode`, typed in `Knuth` and did `M-x reftex-citep`: that had `Knuth` filled in as the regexp value, so I just pressed RET. That gave me a `*RefTex Select*` buffer with four references, I did `r SPG` to restrict it to the single reference that contained the string `SPG`, typed `a` and I got this in the `foo.tex` buffer:

```
Knuth\cite{Knuth:1974:SPG}
```

I don't know much about RefTeX, but that seems to be all correct and working. If that's not what you did and/or expected, then maybe you can edit your question and add the exact behavior you expect and the exact behavior you get.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I was already aware that it needed to be a list, so I am already doing what you're saying.

Comment: You should have added that detail (actually the explicit setting of the variable) to your question: that would prevent earnest but spurious answer attempts like mine  :-) Anyway, this (setting a variable that is supposed to be a list to a non-list value) is a common mistake, so maybe it will help somebody in the future, even if it does not help you now.